# How to make header with picture and text?

Tags: header-footer

I want to make a header which somehow looks like the picture below but I have no idea how to make it. also the name of the organization includes several lines:

[image]

Comment: Welcome, it feels like this question is asked once a week. Where exactly do you have trouble right now, how far did you get? Is that really suppossed to appear on all pages, or just the tite? Is the line underneath intentional?

Comment: i really have no idea on what the code should be. this header and should appear on all pages. also, the line is intentional.

Comment: Three questions in my comment, only one answer.

Comment: If you provide a short sample of what your document looks like right now as [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) those helping you can make sure that the solution actually works for your document set-up. Depending on the document class and additional packages you use not all solutions might be applicable.

Answer (score 4):

This is most conveniently achieved using [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). The commented code below provides what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear all headers/footers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.4pt}% Header rule width
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
\fancyhead[L]{% Left header
  \rule[-1.75\baselineskip]{0pt}{0pt}% Strut to ensure a 1/4 \baselineskip between image and header rule
  \includegraphics[height=3\baselineskip,valign=c]{example-image}% Image
  \quad% Space
  Name of organization% Name
}

\setlength{\headheight}{3.5\baselineskip}% To accommodate new oversized header

\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\sloppy% Just for this example
\lipsum[1-10]% Dummy text

\end{document}
```

If you need the `Name of organization` on multiple lines, I'd suggest using a `tabular`. The default vertical alignment of a `tabular` is centred:

```
  % ...
  \begin{tabular}{l}
    Name \\ of \\ organization% Name
  \end{tabular}
  %...
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! now im having another problem. the text in the header is supposed to be three lines. the format gets messed up whenever i add another line of text in the header

Comment: @PhilCsar: I've added a `tabular` extension to my answer, which allows you to stack content on multiple lines. For future reference, please include *all* relevant details in your original post.